# Is possible to hide the axis on Spotfire visualization?

Tags: data-visualization, spotfire

I have a question that looks pretty easy but it seems it has no simple answer. I have some bar chart Spotfire visualizations and I would like to have a different line instead of the marked as "0" of the X axis. I want to have the Axis fixed as "10" for example (black pointer on the image) and don't have the "0" line by default (blue pointer on the image). I have no problem in the new line creation for reference but I cannot see how remove or hide the default "0" Axis of the Visualization.

[image]

Anyone knows if this is possible? I have searched and tried a lot but didn't find the answer, I understood that with some scripts on Python or something like that it would be possible?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the minimum range of a value axis, which in your case is the `X-Axis`.

- Right click on your visualization
- Click Properties
- Click Value Axis
- Enter 10 in the `Range Min:` box

This may not be applicable for your chart however, since your scale is negative and positive. I'm not sure it's possible to remove a range in the middle, which is what you are trying to do essentially.

Comment: Thank you scsimon. Good tip but yeah it doesn't fit for what I am looking. I would need to "change" the Value of the X Axis to a customized value which it seems is not possible in Spotfire...

Comment: I'm sure it's possible with IronPython

Comment: Yeah I had that supposition too I just acquired the permissions to use scripts so I will try. I will tell you if I succeeded!